# Math Induction to prove recursion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction

This is a problem from a practice test. I don't understand how the answer was produced using math induction. And yes, math induction is required for this problem.

Define a function *f:* $\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{N}$ by

\begin{equation} f(1) = 3 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} f(k+1) = 4k - 2 + f(k)\end{equation}
Use math induction to prove that 
\begin{equation} f(n) = 2n^2 - 4n +5 \text{, for all n}\ge 1 \end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

This is really an exercise in induction.

You need to do the following

1. Verify for $n=1$. This clearly true since $2-4+5 = 3$.
2. Assume it true for $n$ and use it to verify for $n+1$. You should get two formulas for $n+1$, one from the definition of $n$ and the other from what you are trying to prove. Show that they are equal.

Try it and if you get stuck, show me your work and I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Induction has two parts: A base case, corresponding to the smallest value of $n$ (in this case, $1$), and the part where we climb the ladder. The base case is trivial to check.

Now suppose that the result holds for some natural number $n$; we want to prove that the result *also* hold for $n + 1$; we can just compute, though, using the induction hypothesis:

\begin{align*}
f(n + 1) &= 4n - 2 + f(n) \quad \text{(why?)} \\
&= 4n - 2 + \Big(2n^2 - 4n + 5\Big) \quad \text{(why?)} \\
&\vdots \\
&= 2(n + 1)^2 - 4(n + 1) + 5
\end{align*}

which is the desired result.